# I ask for help in running the script to send an email

Tags: google-apps-script

The task of the script is to send me an email if today's date is equal to the date of the call to the client. The script is almost working, I get a message, but without collecting data from rows.

The email that the script sends:

```
Name: 
Status:
1:
2:
3: undefined
4: 23-7-2019
```

```js
function EmailAlert() {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.waitLock(15000);
  Logger.log("Run EmailAlert");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
  Logger.log(ss.getName());
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Customers");
  var message = "";
  var StartRow = 2;

  var columnE = sheet.getRange(2, 5, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1); // get all the rows
  var EValues = columnE.getValues(); // get the values
  var today = new Date();

  for (var i = 0; i < EValues.length; i++)
  { // repeat loop
    var EDate = new Date(EValues[i][0]);
    // 
    var CurrentRow = EValues[i];
    //
    if (EDate.getDate() == today.getDate() &&
      EDate.getMonth() == today.getMonth() &&
      EDate.getFullYear() == today.getFullYear()) {

      var d = today;
      var curr_date = d.getDate();
      var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
      var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

      message +=
        "<p><b> Name: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b> Status: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b> 1: </b>" + CurrentRow[6] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b> 2: </b>" + CurrentRow[8] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b> 3: </b>" + CurrentRow[9] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b> 4: </b>" + curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" +
        curr_year + "</p>" + "</p><br><br>";
      //set the row to look at
      var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;
    } //if review ready
  } //For loop close

  //it's GeneralAlert = "yes" 
  if (GeneralAlert == "yes") {
    var SendTo = (MyEmail + "," + recipientsTO);
  }
  //it's GeneralAlert = "no"
  else {
    var SendTo = (MyEmail)
  }
  //set subject line
  var Subject = "Tasks for today!";

  //send the actual email   if message is not empty
  if (message) {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      bcc: SendTo,
      subject: Subject,
      htmlBody: message,
    });
  }
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! Now, on business trips, this script always remind me who I have to call today! Added working code, maybe someone else will come in handy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Issue:

In your script, `CurrentRow[9]` means that the value is retrieved from the index `9` in each element of `EValues`. But the range of `EValues` is `sheet.getRange(2, 5, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1)`. In this case, the values of only the column "E" are retrieved. And `CurrentRow[9]` is the column "N". In your current script, `EValues` has not values of the column "F" to "N".

#### Modified script:

In order for `CurrentRow[9]` to have the value, it is required to set the range as follows. Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
var columnE = sheet.getRange(2, 5, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);
```

To:

```
var columnE = sheet.getRange(2, 5, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 10);
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, I'm not sure about the values of your Spreadsheet. So if the values of `EValues` you want are not the column "E" to the column "N", it is required to modify the range. At that time, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet?

#### Reference:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function EmailAlert() {
 var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
lock.waitLock(15000);
Logger.log("Run EmailAlert");
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
Logger.log(ss.getName());
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Customers");
var message = "";
var StartRow = 2;

var columnE = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 13); // get all the rows
var EValues = columnE.getValues(); // get the values
var today = new Date(); 
for (var i = 0; i < EValues.length; i++) 

{ // repeat loop
   var EDate = new Date(EValues[i][4]);
   // 
   var CurrentRow = EValues[i];
   //
   if (EDate.getDate() == today.getDate() && 
    EDate.getMonth() == today.getMonth() && 
    EDate.getFullYear() == today.getFullYear())  {

    var d = today;
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

    message +=
      "<p><b> Name: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
        "<p><b> Status: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
          "<p><b> 1: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b> 2: </b>" + CurrentRow[7] + "</p>" +
              "<p><b> 3: </b>" + CurrentRow[8] + "</p>" +
                "<p><b> 4: </b>" + CurrentRow[9] + "</p>" +
                  "<p><b> 5: </b>" + CurrentRow[12] + "</p>" +
                    "<p><b> 6: </b>" + curr_date + "-" + curr_month + 
"-" + curr_year + "</p>" + "</p><br><br>";
    //set the row to look at
    var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;
  }//if review ready
}//For loop close

//it's GeneralAlert = "yes" 
if (GeneralAlert == "yes"){
 var SendTo = (MyEmail + "," + recipientsTO); 
 }
//it's GeneralAlert = "no"
 else {
 var SendTo = (MyEmail)
}
//set subject line
var Subject = "Tasks for today!";

//send the actual email   if message is not empty
if (message) {
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    bcc: SendTo,
    subject: Subject,
    htmlBody: message,
  });
}
 var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
 lock.releaseLock();
}
```